# Image size only half as large as shown in the image file

Tags: javascript

I have a phenomenon that I don’t understand. I have an image file 21600 x 10800

but when i read the width and the height of the picture from the canvas i only get 10800 x 5400

does anyone understand why I only get half of what the image file says it has?

```
const image = await new THREE.ImageLoader().loadAsync('./resources/image0.jpg');    
const map = utils.GetImageData(image);      

//function  
GetImageData: function(image) {
   let canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(image.width, image.height); 
   let context = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
   context.drawImage( image, 0, 0 );
            
   const data = context.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);      
   const width = image.width;
   const height = image.height;

   return {data, width, height};
}
```

why width is only 10800 and not 21600

why height is only 5400 and not 10800

Comment: Does your image have some pixel density info in its EXIF? (look for `XResolution` or `FocalPlaneXResolution`. Could you link to said file? What does `console.log((await createImageBitmap(await fetch("./resources/image0.jpg").then(r=>r.blob()))).width)` output?

Comment: Also, what if you do use `image.naturalWidth` and `image.naturalHeight` everywhere instead of `image.width` and `image.height` (respectively)?

Comment: https://assetsvfx.gumroad.com/l/uHyhPT

Comment: This is the site where i got the image from, the 42k version for testing:    "https://assetsvfx.gumroad.com/l/uHyhPT"  image.naturalWidth and image.naturalHeight unfortunately make no difference. With another image I get the correct values. The problem must lie with the image file. That's a bit of comfort to me again, because it means the code is working properly

Comment: From your link: "Due at 25MB restriction for free product on gumroad, you need to download the link in the txt file for have the best resolution." You need to get the Earth_Previz rar file, in there you'll get links to the actual full quality image in the "Read_plz.txt" file.

Comment: I had read that, but didn't understand it because I saw the jpg preview image 21600 x 10800. So I learned something again, what's on it isn't necessarily what's in the file. Thanks for the clarification